# How to do this in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var tempIdx = document.getElementById('cityBuild').selectedIndex;
var tempBuilding = document.getElementById('cityBuild').options[tempIdx].value;

// Do stuff with tempBuilding
```

I spent some time trying to do it in jQuery under the assumption it'd be easier, it wasn't. I tried what was given at [this site](http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-select-list-values) but is never returned any of the values. Am I doing something wrong or is this something that jQuery simply doesn't do?

The item is a select box (single selection only) and I want to get the value from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery knows how to work with select elements. You can get the value as any other input:

```
var value = $('#cityBuild').val();
```

Comment: That gets the selected text, not the value of the option.

Comment: I thought you wanted the selected text... getting the value is even simpler. Check out my update

Answer (score 4):

Little variation to Eran answer:

```
var value = $('#cityBuild option:selected').val();
```

EDIT: now Eran is in the right. :)

Comment: It is now; it wasn't, originally.

Comment: Thank you, Craig :)  Yes, it was different, i'll update my answer